# Hbase replication Issue

Tags: hbase, hbase-shell

I am using HDP distirbution.I have hbase replication enabled.Firstly it was working fine,but after sometime one RS replication was stucked and in logs I find:

regionserver.ReplicationSourceWALReader: Failed to read stream of replication entries 259735-java.io.EOFException: Cannot seek after EOF 259779- at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.seek